# Flask Restful Api filtering

Tags: python, api, url, flask-restful, restful-url

How do I make the url take filters like this [http://127.0.0.1:5000/books?filter[book_id]>3](http://127.0.0.1:5000/books?filter%5Bbook_id%5D%3E3) ?